# ASP.NET MVC 5.1.x EditorFor Bug

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

If the new EditorFor with htmlAttributes is not working for you, here is what I found:

```
    public bool BoolTest { get; set; }
    public string StringTest { get; set; }
    public int IntTest { get; set; }
    public decimal DecimalTest { get; set; }
    public float FloatTest { get; set; }
    public char CharTest { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeTest { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan TimeSpanTest { get; set; }

// WORKS
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BoolTest, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control bool" } })
// DOESN'T WORK!
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StringTest, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control string" } })
// WORKS
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IntTest, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control int" } })
// DOESN'T WORK!
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DecimalTest, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control decimal" } })
// DOESN'T WORK!
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FloatTest, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control float" } })
// DOESN'T WORK!
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CharTest, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control char" } })
// DOESN'T WORK!
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateTimeTest, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control DateTime" } })
// DOESN'T WORK!
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TimeSpanTest, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control TimeSpan" } })
```

---

**WORKS MEANS:** The input is rendered with the additional htmlAttributes added as expected.

**DOESN'T WORK MEANS:** The input is rendered but no htmlAttributes are passed into the html.

---

Result HTML :

```
<input class="form-control bool check-box" data-val="true" data-val-required="The BoolTest field is required." id="BoolTest" name="BoolTest" type="checkbox" value="true">

<input name="BoolTest" type="hidden" value="false">

<input class="text-box single-line" id="StringTest" name="StringTest" placeholder="" type="text" value="">

<input class="form-control int text-box single-line valid" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field IntTest must be a number." data-val-required="The IntTest field is required." id="IntTest" name="IntTest" type="number" value="0">

<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field DecimalTest must be a number." data-val-required="The DecimalTest field is required." id="DecimalTest" name="DecimalTest" type="text" value="0.00">

<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field FloatTest must be a number." data-val-required="The FloatTest field is required." id="FloatTest" name="FloatTest" placeholder="" type="text" value="0">

<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The CharTest field is required." id="CharTest" name="CharTest" placeholder="" type="text" value="�">

<input class="datefield" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field DateTimeTest must be a date." data-val-required="The DateTimeTest field is required." id="DateTimeTest" name="DateTimeTest" type="text" value="1/1/0001">

<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The TimeSpanTest field is required." id="TimeSpanTest" name="TimeSpanTest" placeholder="" type="text" value="00:00:00">
```

Anyone found a workaround this ? Where should I submit the bug ? (will be great if someone confirmed it it's not my machine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out that I had older EditorTemplates for those primitives which doesn't account for the new htmlAttributes.

Leave the 'problem' here so if anyone finds himself in the same scenario.